Dynamic Programming Issue

So, I'm trying to solve a problem of dynamic programming, where I have this table of operations.
I have, let's say, this sequence: 2⊕2⊕2⊕2⊕1⊕3 = 1 and I want it to be equal to 1.
This sequence has no parentheses, so multiple evaluation orders are possible. The program must determine whether an order of operations exists (using parentheses) such that the sequence matches the expected result. For example, one valid parenthesization for the sequence above is:
((((2⊕2)⊕2)⊕(2⊕1))⊕3) = 1
We need to find the most left-sided parenthesization.
I've come up with a solution that finds every single solution by creating a dp table and computing every subsequence and its value. However, that is extremely inefficient, and for larger inputs takes really long. How can I make it so that this is as fast as possible?
Below is the relevant part of the code

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Structure to store the value and the corresponding expression
struct Result {
    int value;
    string expression;
};

int main() {
    // Optimization to improve the performance of cin/cout (found on the course page)
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0); 

    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m; // Reads n (dimension of the table) and m (length of the sequence).

    // Reads the operation table
    vector<vector<int>> table(n, vector<int>(n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            cin >> table[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Reads the sequence of integers
    vector<int> sequence(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        cin >> sequence[i];
    }

    // Reads the expected result
    int expectedResult;
    cin >> expectedResult;

    // Initializes the DP (dynamic programming) table
    vector<vector<vector<Result>>> dp(m, vector<vector<Result>>(m));

    // Fills the base cases (intervals of size 1)
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        dp[i][i].push_back({sequence[i], to_string(sequence[i])});
    }

    // Fills the intervals of size greater than 1
    for (int len = 2; len <= m; ++len) { // Size of the subsequence interval (minimum 2)
        for (int i = 0; i <= m - len; ++i) { // Start of the interval
            int j = i + len - 1; // End of the interval
            for (int k = i; k < j; ++k) { // Division of the interval, from 1 (second term) to the last j given by interval size - 1
                for (const auto &left : dp[i][k]) {
                    for (const auto &right : dp[k + 1][j]) {
                        int result = table[left.value - 1][right.value - 1];
                        string expr = "(" + left.expression + " " + right.expression + ")"; 
                        dp[i][j].push_back({result, expr});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Filters only the last combination that results in the expected value
    string lastValidExpression = "";
    for (const auto &res : dp[0][m - 1]) {
        if (res.value == expectedResult) {
            lastValidExpression = res.expression; // Updates the expression with the most recently found one
        }
    }

    // Prints the final result (1 or 0)
    if (!lastValidExpression.empty()) {
        cout << "1\n" << lastValidExpression << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "0" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


below are some expected outputs and inputs
Input
2 4 (2 = size of the table, 4 = length of sequence)
(table of operations)
1 2
2 1
1 2 2 1 (sequence)
1 (expected result)

Output:
1 
(((1 2) 2) 1)

Input
3 6
3 2 1
3 2 1
1 3 3
2 2 2 2 1 3
1

Output
1
((((2 2) 2) (2 1)) 3)


Why should ⊕ once bind left and the other time bind right?

@MarekR: return 0 is for main(). dp is a variable. But yes, MRE is required.

@ThomasWeller Ok still this is not MCVE.

Inevitably, when there's a question about "dynamic programming" here, it's from some kind so-called  "competition" site. And your new code contains some tell-tale bad habits used on them (that really aren't needed). Please [edit] your question to include a link to the specific problem, and always ask at that sites forums first. As for the code, it tend to play a smaller role than being able to pick the exact data-structure and algorithm. If your program is too slow, then you likely don't have the right algorithm.

So, i changed the code and now you have access to my full solution. There are a lot of issues with this solution, I know that, but now you have a MRE you can test out. My concerns are:

I need to print out the most left-sided solution, not just any solution.
This uses a lot of memory and takes a lot because the time complexity is exponential. But when I manage to kind of make this faster, I lose the right solution.
Yes this needs to work to every table nxn for every m length sequence


@ScottHunter yes! every n x n table of operations

@Someprogrammerdude this isn't from any website. It's from my past college exam

https://godbolt.org/z/j6cGsYEdq

The only optimization I can see (and it isn't much of one) is to track which of the possible results you can get for each contiguous sub-expression.  So, for example, 2+2+2 can only produce a 2, no matter how you parenthesize it.

Stack Overflow Usage Note: A good title summarizes the technical problem posed by the question. If the title you've come up with will not be recognized as relevant to future readers with a similar problem when it comes up in a search list, the title is not useful.

Did some refactoring to make code easier to test: https://godbolt.org/z/M1h6YdvoG
I see lots of room for improvement: Imperilment a matrix with single vector inside, to reduce cache misses. Do not use string to keep potential result. Transform operation table to use zero based values. Try use brutal force using next_permutaiton (simplifies code and may be faster for small sizes of sequences - it has worse asymptotic time complexity, but much better memory complexity).

If you use ios::sync_with_stdio(0);    cin.tie(0);  you are probably doing competitive coding. The rest of your almost unreadable code style seems to confirm this. Please take some time to learn how to properly use C++ (clear variable names, lots of small functions with also clear names on what they do) and then maybe you have a chance we can read your code to and help you. (This coding style will get you nowhere in a team)

@MarekR This code screams competitive coding, and I fully agree with you this is unreadable, untestable and does not invite any kind of detailed attention

@PepijnKramer . This code isn’t meant for competitive coding. It's for solving
a DP exercise where performance is crucial, and using ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); is a choice made specifically to optimize for speed. It’s a complex problem that requires a more focused approach, and sometimes that means the code won’t look as clean or straightforward. I thank you for your feedback, though it didn't help me much. And I don't get what you mean by untestable when I gave 2 expected outputs and an MRE with less than 80 lines. Remember one day you were also a "not-so-good" programmer.

My intention was not to be mean :) Being a beginner is ok, however coding style (giving proper names to things) is more of a mindset.  The optimization for speed is not found in those kind of details yet (optimization should always be based on measurements, and 9 out of 10 times it is the algorithm that make the real difference). Rule #1 of optmization don't optimize (prematurely).

The remark about testability is indeed a bit too much for this bit of code. But I am used to see complex loops being moved into seperate functions.  So I apologize if my comments where not so helpful

It's okay, thanks for your feedback! I will improve on separating those complex loops into a function to improve readability and start trying to give better names to my variables! Thanks for your feedback! @PepijnKramer

So, I think I have found a better solution, not perfect though, but I will break down some issues I had in my previous solution in case you're interested in this complex DP problem!
So as you can see here, I would store every single possible subsequence, and only then I would check if I had a solution! As you can see in this code, I would search through the DP table, and store the last expression that was a solution. This is extremely inefficient as I just need to find the subsequence more to the left, which in this case would be the last one , because of the order where I was deciding to compute the solutions and add them to DP. The first optimization was to invert the order where this was being computed. I did this so that the most left sided
solution was computed first, not last, and returned immediately the expression of the first valid solution for our problem, instead of adding them all to DP, and then iterating through them
// Filters only the last combination that results in the expected value
string lastValidExpression = "";
for (const auto &res : dp[0][m - 1]) {
    if (res.value == expectedResult) {
        lastValidExpression = res.expression; // Updates the expression with the most recently found one
    }
}

